# Qual o significado do termo: Thread-Agnostic

Tags: característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem

Qual o significado do termo: **Thread-Agnostic**? É possível exemplificar?

> OBS: verifiquei o uso deste termo em uma documentação da Microsoft porém este não estava claro, [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/workflow-execution-properties)

Comment: Não encontrei o termo na documentação citada. Mas de qualquer forma, pela tradução seria independente de thread ou ignorante em relação a threads, não sei se encaixa no contexto em questão.

Comment: @Piovezan no inicio do segundo parágrafo

Comment: Ah tá, em português não aparece. :) não entendi bem a discussão mas seria isso mesmo, um contexto ignorante em relação a threads.

Comment: aahh, @Piovezan você não acredita em mim... :D (piada interna)

Comment: _"que executam em um ambiente neutro em relação a threads"_, ajuda? @Maniero o site estava em português por padrão, mesmo eu não colocando :P (tá eu sei que você não acredita ahahah)

Comment: @Piovezan sim valeu